# Looking to access/output the Associated Image of a page separate from dspBody(). How do I go about doing that?

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I'm trying to access the Associated Image for a page separate from a call to `dspBody()`. I see that I can get it using:

```
#$.content().getImageURL()#
```

But I need a specific defined size of the image. I have several custom sizes defined (like: medium, large, original, etc.).

I've tried passing the size in as a parameter as explained here - [MURA: getImageURL small size cuts off the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527693/mura-getimageurl-small-size-cuts-off-the-image)

```
#$.content().getImageURL(size='original')#
```

But my HTML is coming back empty:

```
<img src="">
```

How do I go about pulling back one of my predefined sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Try it without specifying the `size`. 
This works for me using Mura version 6.2.

```
#$.content().getImageURL('original')#
```

You can change `original` to whatever your custom image size is named.

```
<cfoutput>
<img src="#$.content().getImageURL('customname')#" alt="Alt Title" title="Image Title" />
</cfoutput>
```

See if this way works for you.